# How many objects on stack?

Tags: c++

```
class Object {
       int val;
};

int main() {
       Object Obj;
       Obj = Object();
       return 0;
}
```

How many objects will be there on the stackframe of main after line no 2 in main function i.e after "obj = Object()" assuming there is no optimization used during compilation?

Comment: [None](http://goo.gl/I5vn8z)

Comment: why do you say that?

Comment: @user114754 did you look at the assembly?

Comment: No. I am not familiar to assembly. What should I look for in assembly code?

Comment: How many objects... at what point in time? If you're optimizing, then chances are the answer is none, ever, since the object is never used after construction and has no side-effects, so it might be completely optimized away. But for an unoptimized build, you might have one (default constructed) after the first line, two at some point during the execution of the second line, and back to one after that. But they might also be in registers instead of the stack, or something, as well...

Comment: Thanks twalberg. I have edited my question as per your answer. Sorry for the confusion caused. I am curious whether there will be two objects on stack during the life time of the main function, since we are constructing two objects at line 1 and line 2 but not destroying any one of them. Though, Just one will be accessible through 'Obj'.

Comment: @user114754, The first line is a label for the `main` subroutine. `xorl %eax, %eax` is an XOR, and anything XOR itself is zero. `retq` is to return from a subroutine (the return value is `%eax`, which is 0). That's the only assembly there, indicating a program that does nothing. My point was that compilers are good at what they do.

Comment: @user114754, Theoretically, there would be an object that exists for all of `main` and one temporary that exists for one line. Both are destroyed automatically.

Comment: @chris Thanks. At line no 2, second temp object is constructed, its content are copied to first object and temp object is destroyed. Now, this temp object will be on the stack or heap or we cant say for sure?

Comment: Nothing is on the heap unless you ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

As there is only one variable there is only one object on the stack.

Comment: yep. The variable means space on the stack. C++ oposite to managed languages does't free stack space before scope end

Comment: What about the temporary objected created?

Comment: Just prove with memory dump in Visual Studio with disabled optimisations and it proves that Temp object are on the stack as well. The order of variables on the stack was little bit unexpected for me because in some cases the temp variables were before first variable on the stack.